# Fancybox 3 Style Issue

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox

[image: Messed up Fancybox Style]

When I click one of the preview images, in order to bring up the fancybox gallery, it just swipes the image to the right and gives me this broken overlay. Not sure what the issue is here...

HTML (Note I'm using WordPress and Advanced Custom fields):

```html
<?php if ( have_rows("inspiration_gallery") ) : ?>

      <?php $i = 0; while ( have_rows("inspiration_gallery") ) :
        the_row();
        $img = get_sub_field("inspiration_image");
        $img_id = $img['ID'];
        $img_url = $img['url'];
        $gallery_id = $gallery_id ? $gallery_id : $img_id;
        $related = get_sub_field("inspiration_related");
      ?>

        <?php if ($i == 0): ?>
          <!-- Preview Image -->
          <a class="inspiration__preview-link" href="<?php echo esc_url($img_url); ?>" data-fancybox="gallery-<?php echo esc_attr($gallery_id); ?>">
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $img_id, "full", false, array("class" => "inspiration__prev_img") ); ?>
          </a>

        <?php else: ?>

          <!-- Gallery Fancybox Link -->
          <a class="inspiration__gallery-link none" href="<?php echo esc_url($img_url); ?>" data-fancybox="gallery-<?php echo esc_attr($gallery_id); ?>"></a>

        <?php endif; ?>

      <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

I've got the latest versions of Fancybox JS and CSS files enqueued.

Comment: Looks like either a position or z-index issue, the PHP code doesn't help, could you link a reproducible demo?

Comment: I don't think so...I feel as if I try to recreate it, it'll just work fine, but I don't know what the issue is here.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough information for me to be able to help, sorry. Maybe try posting your CSS / HTML output?

Comment: I found the issue...basically I think what happened was I was using the CSS from a different version of FancyBox, and it wasn't working with the JS version.